# Automatically crop gnuplot output

Tags: pdf, gnuplot, crop

`gnuplot` can plot data to a file like `pdf`. Then one can for instance use `pdflatex` to generate a paper that uses the generated plot.

A problem is that both `gnuplot` and `pdflatex` add some margin to the file. As a result, the margins of the final paper are quite large.

One can use `pdfcrop` to remove the witespace such that the paper is structured more compact.

I'm wondering however whether there is a way to automatically crop the ouput of `gnuplot`, for instance by activating a setting in `gnuplot`.

Until now, the `make` script worked as follows:

**`plotter.gnuplot`**

```
set terminal pdf
set output 'temp.pdf'
plot "data.dat" u 1 t "f(x)" w lines
```

**`makefile`**

```
all : plotter.gnuplot data.dat
    gnuplot < plotter.gnuplot
    pdfcrop "temp.pdf" "somefile.pdf"
    rm "temp.pdf"
    pdflatex book.tex
```

Where `book.tex` includes `somefile.pdf`.

Comment: I don't really see the point. For `pdflatex` you can tweak everything you want (size of figure with `\includegraphics` and margins with the `geometry` package). For `gnuplot`, you can tweak margins, see `help set margin`). What more can be done ? And I think `\includegraphics` also has a "crop" option...

Comment: I think that the question is pertinent. There is a need to crop without looking at the bounding box values and using them in  `\includegraphics` (with trim=l b r t), neither using an additional command like `pdfcrop` nor cropping with an external tool like `skim` on OS/X. The crop command works in gif terminal: `set ter gif crop` but not in pdfcairo.

Comment: In order to shorten your script, you can use the same filename:`pdfcrop "somefile.pdf" "somefile.pdf"` because pdfcrop rename its temporary pdf file to the output filename. Also, you can insert this command into you gnuplot script file using an exclamation mark on first character: `!pdfcrop "somefile.pdf" "somefile.pdf"`. It may not work on windows if you haven't a correct shell.

Answer (score 1):

Some output drivers support the `crop` parameter that removes most of the unused whitespace of the canvas automatically. It is not as thorough as `pdfcrop` but at least creates a uniform margin. To generate PDFs you can use `pdfcairo` as below but `Cairolatex` or `Tikz` with the `tightboundingbox` option might work even better to integrate plots into Latex documents.

```
set term pdfcairo enhanced crop
```